# Purge and recreate cache of a specific URL in Nginx proxy cache

Tags: nginx, caching, cache-control, nginx-cache

I have some websites using Nginx `fcgi_cache` to serve guests faster. but some day I update a menu in header or update a page.

**Note: I have tried [`proxy_cache_purge` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_purge) and It's part of nginx commercial subscription.**

Now I'm looking for a solution to purge specific URL or purge all cache at once.

Please provide me a free solution if there is one!